# Composer\Downloader\TransportException

Tags: composer-php, packagist

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_l>composer update 

The "https://original.packagist.jp/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
https://original.packagist.jp could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date
Loading composer repositories with package information
The "https://original.packagist.jp/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
https://original.packagist.jp could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "https://original.packagist.jp/p/doctrine/dbal%2417ae46d6beb8d0b5cfd7df33d21dbd21443feeaf54bdc9d841ac03de5ab99c
  1d.json" file could not be downloaded: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
  failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.


update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [-i|--interactive] [--root-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
```

Hi guys i have error. I could't download everything after I had installed pagkage Prestissimo

Comment: Obviously, the server `original.packagist.jp` is not available. Can you attach your `composer.json` to the question?

Comment: pagkage: socialite providers/manager

Comment: Please attach the **whole** file to your question. Somewhere in the file is an error